# Why does enumitem need the macro to exist already?

Tags: macros, enumitem, pgfmath

I'm using `pgf` and `enumitem` to define a hexadecimal enumeration scheme as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,enumitem}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\Hex}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@Hex\csname c@#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand*{\@Hex}[1]{%
  \pgfmathdectoBase\The@Hex{#1}{16}\The@Hex
}

\AddEnumerateCounter{\Hex}{\@Hex}{E}

%------------------------------------------------------------
% Why does cutting this line cause it to fail?
%------------------------------------------------------------
\AtBeginDocument{\pgfmathdectoBase\The@Hex{1}{16}}
%------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\Hex*]
\item First
\item Second\addtocounter{enumi}{10}
\item Letters
\item More
\item Another
\item Ten!
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Now if I remove the highlighted line, the compilation fails and I can't understand why. It tells me:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \The@Hex
```

I'm trying to understand why it needs this macro to already be defined for the enumeration to work, especially since the value of `\The@Hex` isn't actually used until it is redefined by the use of enumerate...

Comment: Smells after an `\edef` context where the `\The@Hex` in `\pgfmathdectoBase\The@Hex{..` is expanded. A typical fragility issue. It works when you use `\DeclareRobustCommand` to define `\Hex`. The question is: why does it work anyway then?

Comment: @Martin: Never use `\DeclareRobustCommand` for things to which you would apply `\label` and `\ref`.

Comment: @egreg: you are totally right; I agree. However, Seamus code is fragile and therefore doesn't work with these macros anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a way that avoids assignments, making conversion to hexadecimal completely expandable:

```
\input{binhex}
\newcommand*{\Hex}[1]{\expandafter\hex\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\Hex}{\hex}{E}
```

`binhex.tex` is by David Kastrup.

As partly explained by Martin, one problem with `\pgfmathdectoBase` that performs assignments and so it's unusable in defining number representations for `\ref`, because the system has to use `\edef` (in the form of `\protected@edef`) in order to write in the aux file the actual number and not a command. With your definition, assigning `\label` to an item and trying `\ref` with it would result in an error.

Since an `enumerate` is probably not too long, one can use

```
\newcommand{\Hex}[1]{\expandafter\@Hex\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@Hex[1]{\ifnum#1>15 \@ctrerr\else\hexnumber@{#1}\fi}
```

maybe extending the definition of `\hexnumber@` to cover more cases.

Comment: Nice. I was just going to point out that LaTeX provides `\def\hexnumber@#1{\ifcase\number#1
 0\or 1\or 2\or 3\or 4\or 5\or 6\or 7\or 8\or
 9\or A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\fi}`
which could also be expanded to number larger than 15.

Comment: I was wondering about this. Loading `pgf` seems rather excessive just to get hex numbers...

Comment: `fmtcount` also provides hex as well as binary, octal and a bunch of other formats...

Comment: Always non expandable, though.

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused because the label code is supposed to by fully expandable. Your one is actually fragile which causes the `\The@Hex` in `\pgfmathdectoBase\The@Hex` to be expanded before it got assigned (there is a `\protected@edef` used to set the `\@currentlabel` in `\refstepcounter`.). The solution for this is to change your definition of the macro. As egreg pointed out making the macro robust would avoid that error but cause issues when the enumeration item is `\label`ed. Note that LaTeX provides the macro `\hexnumber@` which can be used for the number 0-15 (See egreg's answer for are bigger range).

Comment: Bigger range indeed! `\hex` manages numbers up to 2147483647, which is the greatest legal number in TeX. `binhex.tex` manages also bases 2, 4 and 8.

Comment: @egreg: Wow, imagine an enumerate with 2147483647 items! ;-)  (I just posted the answer to explicitly point out the source of the trouble; which seemed to be the main reason why Seamus asked the question)